# unpredictable answer in bitfield

Tags: c

Could you please explane to me why the output of this code is 12 (1100b)

and how the sizeof(bit1) is 4byte???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct bitfield
  {
   unsigned a:5;
   unsigned c:5;
   unsigned b:6;

  };

void main()
{

 char *p;
 struct bitfield bit1={1,3,3};  //a=00001 ,c=00011 ,b=000011
 p=&bit1;                           // p get the address of bit1
 p++;                               // incriment the address of p in 1

 printf("%d\n",*p); 

 printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit1));            
}
```

Comment: You might want to review the standard on member-addresses, bitfield members, and how bitfields are "special". I'm also curious how you're *not* getting a phat warning with that direct assignment to `char *` from a `struct bitfield *` type.

Comment: doesn't the sizeof(bit1) is 2byte(16bit)
and output should be 195(11000011b)???

Comment: @Anklon The compiler typically will add padding to `struct`s for alignment purposes (so that you could create an array of them).  Your compiler might have something like a `#pragma pack` option to control that. http://www.c-faq.com/struct/endpad.html

Comment: C99 6.7.2.1p11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

Comment: I suggest using `%zu` to print values of the type `size_t` (eg. the result of a `sizeof` expression).

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your bit fields as `unsigned`. On most modern systems, that's a 32 bit integer. (unsigned short is 16, char 8, long 64, etc.) So, you're declaring a 32 bit bitfield container. The size of each individual bit field argument is given by the integer after the bitfield name, but the size of the container they are packed in is a multiple of the data type specified... typically the smallest multiple the total indicated number of bits will fit in -- though word boundaries and other things will play into that.

I'm surprised any of the rest of it works at all. Aside from the casting issues in the pointer, the printf is printing the first 8 bits of the entire field... a single char. That will not break on the bit fields themselves, but on the byte/char memory boundary. Depending on whether your system is big endian or little endian, it will be either the MSB or LSB of the entire field.

Comment: Um, no. The size of a bit field is determined by the number following it; the widths in bits are 5, 5, and 6 respectively.

Comment: The size of the **individual** bit fields, yes. But the size of the container they are packed in is defined by the type. It will be a multiple of the type.

Comment: when I mention it as signed or don't mension it as signed or unsigned...both case it shows sizeof(bit1) is 4 byte ...

Comment: And if you declare is an `unsigned short`?

Comment: you say "it will be multiple of the type"..
then it should be 4*3=12 byte as unsigned int is also 4bytes (for my compiler)

Comment: Yes... if you use an `unsigned short` then the size of the structure itself will be some multiple of the size of an `unsigned short` depending on how many bits you declare in the fields. If you declare 16 or fewer bits, the structure will use a single `unsigned short` to hold them. If you add another field that pushes it to 20 bits, then it will use two to hold them up until it reaches 32 bits, then it will add another. etc. However, it is possible, too, that it will use larger numbers if word boundaries come into play (such as using a `unsigned char` instead of `unsigned short`

Comment: @Keith Thompson -- read it again. I've clarified the difference between the size of an individual bit field and the container they are stored in. The size of the individual bit field is (obviously) defined by the integer after it, but I was talking about the bitfield **container** they are **all** contained in.

Comment: @KScottPiel: Ok, I misread it. But what's your basis for asserting that the size of a struct containing bit fields depends on the declared types of the bit fields? Note that the only *portable* types for bit fields are `signed int`, `unsigned int`, `int` (which may refer to either `signed int` or `unsigned int`) and `_Bool`; a compiler may, but need not, permit `unsigned short` bit fields, for example. (I see that gcc does behave as you describe, but I don't see any such requirement in the C standard.)

Comment: I'm not saying necessarily that it's a requirement, so much as I was explaining why the sizeof() was 4 bytes... which was his question. It's 4 bytes because the size of an unsigned int is 4 bytes on most systems. However, it could be larger, as well... the only way for it to be smaller (I believe he was expecting 16 bits or 2 bytes) is **if** his system supports the use of unsigned short or chooses (optionally) to use smaller container sizes (most don't)

Comment: "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field." I read that as allowing the compiler to freely choose the underlying type, as long as it's large enough.

Comment: @KScottPiel: As far as I can tell from reading the standard, a system with 32-bit `int` could have `sizeof (struct { unsigned bf: 1; }) == 1`. The width of the bit field is 1 bit, not 32. I can't figure out where the gcc authors got the idea that an `unsigned int` bit field requires the containing struct to be at least as big as an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Ultimately, the bitfield has to get stored in memory and the smallest unit of storage in memory is (typically) 8 bits... a single byte. So, the smallest a bitfield container could ever be is a single byte and it could be any multiple of bytes from there up. Other things also play out... register size (32 bit registers?) and other potential CPU gains, memory efficiency (native bus widths?), etc. etc. etc. Who knows. On modern systems, char is not always the most efficient way to do things. But, point taken all the same.

Comment: @KScottPiel: I've asked about this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15980589/827263).

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `p` contains the address of structure variable `bit1`.

I believe your system is having **little endian** addressing due to which the variable `b` is placed in the location pointed by pointer p and *p prints the content of the first two bytes of `bit1`.

In your case `b=3   (000011)`

But the two bytes contains,

```
00000000 00001100  (12)
         ------
            ^
            |
         Value of b
```

To better understand this,

change the value of `b` to 5 (000101) as follows,

```
struct bitfield bit1={1,1,5};
```

Then your output will be 20 because,

```
00000000 00010100  (20)
         ------
           ^
           |
        Value of b
```

The structure `bitfield` packs `a`, `c` and `b` into a single unsigned integer. The size of unsigned integer is **4 Bytes**.