# Why would the type of a bit field affect the size of the containing structure?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

First, here's what the ISO C standard says about bit fields, quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the 2011 ISO C Standard, section 6.7.2.1:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified
>   version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other
>   implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether
>   atomic types are permitted.

...

> A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type
>   consisting of the specified number of bits. If the value 0 or 1 is
>   stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type `_Bool`, the value of
>   the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool`
>   bit-field has the semantics of a `_Bool`.
>
> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that
>   immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed
>   into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or
>   overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of
>   allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or
>   low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of
>   the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

For any `struct` type, the alignment of the type is at least the maximum alignment of any member of the type, and the size of any type is a multiple of its alignment. For example, if a structure contains a (non-bit-field) `int` member, and `int` requires 4-byte alignment, then the structure itself requires 4-byte alignment or more.

Many compilers permit bit fields of integer types other than `_Bool` and the `int` types.

For at least some compilers, the alignment of a `struct` containing a bit field is at least the alignment of *the declared type* of the bit field.  For example, for gcc 4.7.2 on x86_64, given:

```
struct sb {
    _Bool bf:1;
};
struct si {
    unsigned bf:1;
};
```

gcc gives `struct sb` a size and alignment of 1 byte (which is the size and alignment of `_Bool`), and `struct si` a size and alignment of 4 bytes (which is the size and alignment of `int`).  It does the same thing with bit fields of implementation-defined types; a bit field defined as `long long bf:1;` forces an 8-byte size and alignment for the enclosing structure. This is done even though in both cases the bit field `bf` is an object whose width is just 1 bit.

I've seen similar behavior with Sun's compiler on SPARC/Solaris 9.

Experiment shows that multiple bit fields defined either as `_Bool` or as `unsigned` can be packed into adjacent bits within a single byte (in fact that's required), so the bit fields themselves do not have strict alignment requirements.

I understand that the layout of struct members is largely implementation-defined, and I don't believe that gcc's behavior violates the C standard.

So my question (*finally!*) is, why does gcc (along with at least one unrelated C compiler, and probably more) do this? Do the authors of gcc assume that the declared type of a bit field must affect the size and alignment of the containing struct? Are they correct in this assumption? Is there a requirement in the C standard itself that I've missed?

Here's a test program that exhibits the behavior. If you want to run it on your system, you might need to comment out parts of it, if you're using an old compiler that doesn't support some of the newer features, or one that doesn't permit certain types of bit fields. I'd be interested in knowing if there are compilers that *don't* behave as gcc does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
    struct sb  { _Bool    bf:1; };
    struct s8  { uint8_t  bf:1; };
    struct s16 { uint16_t bf:1; };
    struct s32 { uint32_t bf:1; };
    struct s64 { uint64_t bf:1; };
    printf("sizeof (struct sb)  = %2zu (%2zu bits)\n",
           sizeof (struct sb),
           sizeof (struct sb)  * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("sizeof (struct s8)  = %2zu (%2zu bits)\n",
           sizeof (struct s8),
           sizeof (struct s8)  * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("sizeof (struct s16) = %2zu (%2zu bits)\n",
           sizeof (struct s16),
           sizeof (struct s16) * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("sizeof (struct s32) = %2zu (%2zu bits)\n",
           sizeof (struct s32),
           sizeof (struct s32) * CHAR_BIT);
    printf("sizeof (struct s64) = %2zu (%2zu bits)\n",
           sizeof (struct s64),
           sizeof (struct s64) * CHAR_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output I get on my system:

```
sizeof (struct sb)  =  1 ( 8 bits)
sizeof (struct s8)  =  1 ( 8 bits)
sizeof (struct s16) =  2 (16 bits)
sizeof (struct s32) =  4 (32 bits)
sizeof (struct s64) =  8 (64 bits)
```

Comment: Inspired by a discussion in comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15977101/827263).

Comment: clang (at least the one I have installed on the 32 bit box I'm currently on) says 32 bits for the `struct s64`, and so says my gcc here.

Comment: @DanielFischer clang 3.0, icc 13.1.1, tcc 0.9.25 and gcc 4.7 produce the exact output posted by Keith. (on an amd64 box)

Comment: @cnicutar Doesn't surprise me, I'm on a 32-bit box now, as I said, and 32-bits is the maximal alignment requirement here. I think the rationale is to interpret the specified type as an alignment request. So you get the alignment you requested, or the maximal if you wanted more.

Comment: If you compile with `-Wpadded`, you'll get a few of `warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]` (clang also says how much padding is added). That seems to corroborate that the compiler takes the specified type as an alignment hint. Probably assuming the programmer knows what (s)he's doing by declaring a type larger than necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a way you've answered the question yourself with this quotation from the standard:

> The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

The compiler can choose any alignment and adhere to the C standard, but that's not the whole story.

In order for code compiled with different compilers to interoperate, the platform ABI must specify these details. For example the SYS-V i386 ABI used by Linux x86 says:

> Bit-fields obey the same size
>   and alignment rules as other structure and union members, with the following
>   additions: [...]
>
> - A bit-field must entirely reside in a storage unit appropriate for its declared
>     type.

It then follows that regardless of the width, a `long` bitfield must reside in something that is aligned on a 4 byte boundary.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I've answered the question myself. In any case, that raises another question: what's the rationale for that requirement in the ABI? I suppose it has to enforce *some* rule, but why that one? (I could almost quibble about what "its declared type" means; the C standard says "A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the
specified number of bits.", but the context in [the ABI document](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) implies that the "type" of `int bf:1` is `int`.)

Comment: `int bf: 1` can entirely reside in a u8 storage unit, and u8 is appropriate. If you add __attribute__((packed)) after the struct declaration, sizeof struct will be 1. See https://godbolt.org/z/9nEf6aWzs. Or __attribute__((packed)) violates the ABI spec?